# django runserver in http

Tags: python, django

I'm a little new to django so bear with me. I have an app that's running just fine in HTTPS. In settings.py I have this bit of line that enables it:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Out of curiosity, instead of disabling this every time to test pages and applications, is there a way to enable http for **only** 127.0.1:8000 and **not** *.example.com? Or is this a bad practice to even attempt?

Comment: I would consider making these variables as environmental variables

Comment: Can you expand on that @JPG? I don't understand, do you mean making the booleans an environment variable or the HTTP strings?

Comment: @KaelanO'reily I have provided a solution using custom middleware which you may check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easier than I imagined.

```
import sys
if 'runserver' in sys.argv:
    DEBUG = True
    PREPEND_WWW = False
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
else:
    DEBUG = False
    PREPEND_WWW = True
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a good practice to use HTTPS in production but for the local development you can use HTTP without any issues.
You can do this by creaying a custom middleware where you can customly define and enforces HTTPS only for certain hostnames and HTTP for localhost.

To do this follow these steps:
Create a custom middleware file inside your app directory and name it as you like for example `custom_middleware.py`

**Add this code to the custom middleware:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
from django.conf import settings

class CustomHttpsMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Check if not in debug mode and not a local IP
        if not settings.DEBUG and not request.META['HTTP_HOST'].startswith('127.0.0.1'):
            # Redirect to HTTPS
            if not request.is_secure():
                request_url = request.build_absolute_uri(request.get_full_path())
                secure_url = request_url.replace('http://', 'https://')
                return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(secure_url)

        return self.get_response(request)
```

***Note: If you need more information how to create custom middleware in dajngo you can check here:*** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

Add the newly created middleware to your project `settings.py` file

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'yourapp.custom_middleware.CustomHttpsMiddleware',
    # ...
]
```

***Make sure to replace 'yourapp' with the your appname or folder name where you placed the custom_middleware.py file.***

Comment: I like the solution but it didn't exactly work on my end, this may just be a user error. Please correct me if I am misunderstanding but when we load into the main page, this forces an addition to the http with the https, but when I tried it, it didn't work. In fact it threw a few errors, this may be on my end. I'm still testing it out. Could my settings be overriding it? I removed them as well and that didn't seem to do much. 

I wanted to spend some time debugging it before I approved an answer so I may be missing something as well. Let me know if there's more I need to do. :)

Comment: @KaelanO'reily You are correct. Could you please specify what errors you are getting so I can further investigate?

Comment: It looks like since I was sending data to a google geomap api in my application, it was forcing it to load in https so that was my fault. Also brings into question on how it can be used. Looks like there's more to learn. I'll mark this as completed as it did answer the initial question. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my solution, the easiest approach was to import sys.

Answer (score 1):

I would set these settings variables as environmental variables and feed them dynamic data according to the env. I'm a great fan of [`django-environ`](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package and I'm gonna use that here as well.

I would change my `settings.py` file as below to pick the values from running environment,

```
# settings.py
from environ import Env

env = Env()
# other settings

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = env.tuple("SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER", default=("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https"))
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = env.bool("SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT", default=True)
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = env.bool("SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE", default=True)
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = env.bool("CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE", default=True)
```

So, the above settings will search for the values in the current running environment, and if found a match, it will be used — otherwise, fallback to the `default` value.

In your case, if you are developing the app on your local machine, make sure to set (or export) the env variables;

```
export SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER=""
export SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False
export SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False
export CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=False
```

Comment: This may not work as the website is ran on the local machine as well. That is all part of the website, from hardware to software are on the same machine. So in development, this would be the same as prod no? It's a hobbyist website for myself so I figured this would be cheaper than spending 50-70$ hosting an ec2 instance or something of the sort to host everything.

Comment: You can change the env values as per your environment, I don't understand the problem you are referring here

Comment: I'm just trying to get a better understanding. If I had come off the wrong way, my apologies. 
Let's say I use env.bool("SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE", default=True), how would the .env know which to use? Would the 127 local host be what determines the value to be false? I'm currently using the .env right now for some passwords and s3 buckets so may be confused on how to fully use the .env.

Comment: Your application is determining which env should use (most of the application/packaged search for a `.env` file on the project root) also also comes with an option to specify custom env file as well

Comment: I updated my solution, the easiest approach was to import sys.